'List<Comment>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>'
posts.dart file
return ListView(
  shrinkWrap: true, //for nested lists
  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((doc) {
    //get the comment
    final commentData = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

    //return the comment
    return Comment(
      text: commentData["CommentText"], 
      user: commentData["CommentedBy"], 
      time: formatDate(commentData["CommentTime"]),
    );
  }).toList(),
);

comment.dart file
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Comment extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final String user;
  final String time;
  const Comment({
    super.key,
    required this.text,
    required this.user,
    required this.time,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.grey[300],
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          //comment
          Text(text),

          //user time
          Row(
            children: [
              Text(user),
              Text(" . "),
              Text(time),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Comment() class is not getting recognized by the ListView and to make it work I even put toList() method at the end of the bracket but it still gives the error I have written in the title.
You can also take a look at the comment.dart file which describes the Comment method. I'm confused as to why isn't it exporting in the main file.

Your Comment class does not extend StatelessWidget or Stateful widget.

Seems like you are using Comment class which is not a type of widget and ListView expects to return a Widget. You can create a custom widget which can hold Comment object as a parameter or Comment class parameters and then try returing that custom widget from the listview. Hopes this helps, if not you can provide the content of Comment and I can help you further with that.

@SanchitArora I have created a file comment.dart to explain the comment class but still the persists. can you take a look at it?   I'm adding it in the question!

Does this answer your question? type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'List' I think you just need to change map() to map<Widget>()

I saw that you edited the question, if Comment class extends StatelessWidget like you the code you provided, it can't show the error message that you are saying!

Try to use listview of comment
return ListView<Comment>(
  ..
)


Could you provide detailed error messages and screenshots of the errors? Otherwise, it's challenging for me to determine the issue you're encountering. I've implemented a test case based on the code snippets you provided, and I didn't encounter the error you mentioned.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    class CommentModel{
      final String text;
      final String user;
      final String time;
      const CommentModel({
        required this.text,
        required this.user,
        required this.time,
      });
    
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      const MyApp({super.key});
    
      @override
      State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
    }
    
    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
      final List<CommentModel> comments = [
        CommentModel(
          text: "This is a comment",
          user: "User1",
          time: "12:00",
        ),
        CommentModel(
          text: "This is another comment",
          user: "User2",
          time: "12:01",
        ),
      ];
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            body: ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true, //for nested lists
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              children:comments.map((doc) {
                //get the comment
                final commentData = doc;
                //return the comment
                return Comment(
                  text: commentData.text,
                  user: commentData.user,
                  time: commentData.time,
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    
    class Comment extends StatelessWidget {
      final String text;
      final String user;
      final String time;
      const Comment({
        super.key,
        required this.text,
        required this.user,
        required this.time,
      });
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey[300],
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              //comment
              Text(text),
    
              //user time
              Row(
                children: [
                  Text(user),
                  Text(" . "),
                  Text(time),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }


My speculation is that your snapshot.data!.docs is empty, resulting in a null return, which caused this error. However, I cannot confirm this idea without seeing detailed information.
